# Point on arc at Angle

Tags: geometry

[image]

Is it possible to find "???", also the center points X & Y are known.

Comment: Is the horizontal green line tangent to the red circle? It's a bit difficult to tell.

Comment: If the center point is known, use $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2$, where you know all but $y$. $$y=y_c\pm\sqrt{r^2-(x-x_c)^2}.$$

Comment: the Horizontal Green line is not at a tangent, Ty for your answers so far.